# Issue with prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In the following code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn
                .prepareStatement(SQLQueries.isMuted);
        statement.setString(1, player);
        statement.setString(2, player);
//in SQLQueries.java
public static final String isMuted = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "
        + "(SELECT playerid FROM mute, players AS player "
        + "WHERE player.username = '?' AND playerid = player.id"
        + "UNION ALL "
        + "SELECT playerid FROM tempmute, players AS player "
        + "WHERE player.username = '?' AND playerid = player.id) AS tbl) "
        + "AS isMuted;";
```

I get the following error:

```
[08:10:38 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

I am very confused by that, because the documentation told me the parameter index starts at 1, and this is confirmed, because when I changed the setString statements to 0 and 1, respectivly, it gave me another error. Also, the statement has two placeholders, so I do not understand why this code fails.

Have I overlooked something in the documentation?

Comment: Maybe you added parameters to `SQLQueries.isMuted` instead of `isBanned`?

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the quotes around the parameters?

Comment: I think Keppil is right - Java does not see any parameters in the SQL, it sees (and is not concerned with) a condition checking for equality with the literal string containing exactly one question mark. So change '?' with ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the `?` PreparedStatement placeholders.  The JDBC driver will quote the strings for you.  When you quote the string placeholder yourself, the JDBC driver thinks you want to pass a literal `?` in your statement.

You haven't mentioned the database you are using, but the main author for the MySQL JDBC driver confirms this here:  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,499385,499450#msg-499450

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after `player.id`:

```
public static final String isBanned = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "
        + "(SELECT playerid FROM bans, players AS player "
        + "WHERE player.username = '?' AND playerid = player.id "
---------------------------------------------------------------^
        + "UNION ALL "
        + "SELECT playerid FROM tempban, players AS player "
        + "WHERE player.username = '?' AND playerid = player.id) AS tbl) "
        + "AS isBanned;";
```

There might be other problems as well.

Comment: I have added a space, but that doesn't seem to fix it.